# html toggle divs

Tags: html

i have the following code :

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script>
function showMe (it, box) {
  var vis = (box.checked) ? "none" : "block";
  document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('div1', this)">Show Hide Checkbox
<div id="div1">
<h3 align="center"> test </h3>

</div>
<form>
</form>
</body>
```

I want to toggle the div, the code above works however when the script loads the div is visible. How can i set the div to hidden when the script loads? (i know that if i set the div outside the  tags it works however i want to toggle them inside).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `div` tag to `display:none` initially. And flip the condition of the `if`.

Like:

```
function showMe (it, box) {
    var vis = (box.checked) ? "block":"none";
   document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
}


<div id="div1" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar on one of my pages and I include this in the div

```
style="display:none"
```

That seems to work for me, and then it gets changed to block when i click my show/hide button